# Vue.js - rounding off digits giving me bizarre figures

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm calculating my totals and then i want them to be fixed to 2 decimal places.Check my code below.

```
this.selectedCompaniesDetails.forEach((company)=>{
                            if(company.id == p.company_id)
                            {
                                if (!tot[p.company_id])
                                {   tot[p.company_id] = [] }
                                    const numberPrice = parseFloat(p.price)
                                
                                 tot[p.company_id].push(numberPrice)
                            }
                        });
```

The parseFloat(p.price) function is giving me weird answers. Check my screen shot below.
[image]

Comment: What is `p.price` and what is `numberPrice`? What did you expect. Your screenshot does not explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```js
let num = 5.56789;
let n = num.toFixed(2);

console.log(num);
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2"`

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
   return +(Math.round(num + "e+2")  + "e-2");
}

let number = 139.605;
let round = roundToTwo(number)
var f = number .toFixed(2);

console.log('original', number);
console.log('expected', 139.61);
console.log('(Correct)round', round);
console.log('(Wrong)toFixed', f);
```

Comment: Using your method i get some totals rounded to 1 decimal place because they have a leading zero... For example some of my outcomes are like this, 761.45 and 696.2